# Remove day name from DateTimePicker

Tags: .net, winforms, datetime, format, datetimepicker

I have a `DateTimePicker` and it is currently displaying **"Friday, June 26 2009"**

How would I change it so it displays **"June 26 2009"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code worked for me

```
    DTP_deltek.CustomFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy";
    DTP_deltek.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Answer (score 7):

[`DateTimePicker.CustomFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

```
myDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd yyyy";
```

You can set this in this in the designer too.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) is your friend.

Comment: actually i gave it a try from the designer too and it didnt work? there should be no diffrence between doing it code time or design time should there?